# Entender a mensagem de erro do eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Ultimamente minha plataforma de desenvolvimento não está colaborando comigo, eu tenho criando os projetos e não compila, procedimentos que tenho feito são os mais corretos, então resolvi procurar o log de erros do eclipse, e terminei encontrando uma tonelada de erros, eu postei o ultimo erro para me ajudarem baseado no ultimo log de erro.

```
Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.ui/icons/full/eview16/vm_explorer.png
```

Exception stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.jboss.tools.jmx.jvmmonitor.ui/icons/full/eview16/vm_explorer.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getStream(URLImageDescriptor.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getImageData(URLImageDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getImageData(URLImageDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ViewLabelProvider.getImage(ViewLabelProvider.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider.update(ColumnLabelProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedState(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2500)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree$2.recursiveExpand(FilteredTree.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree$2.runInUIThread(FilteredTree.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openOther(ShowViewHandler.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.execute(ShowViewHandler.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowViewMenu$3.run(ShowViewMenu.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Session Data

```
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

então porque meu eclipse está doente?
o que é necessário para corrigir isso?
vou ter que instalar outra versão de eclipse?

Comment: você instalou algum plugin recentemente ? se instalou, tente reiniciar o computador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece na instalação de um determinado Plugin, quando esta baixando as dependências do mesmo pode haver intermitência na rede e não conclui com sucesso os Downloads necessários, ja passei por isso algumas vezes.
Basta baixar novamente o plugin ou remover ele por completo.

NO seu caso é o Plugin que esta na mensagem mesmo, o

> jvmmonitor ou o Jboos

Comment: como se encontrar um plugin. No site do eclipse acho um pouco confuso, ainda mais que é inglês. Meu eclipse dá erro quando vou abrir um arquivo e só aparece ok e detalhes. Quando clico em ok, tenho acesso para editar normalmente, mas isso as vezes incomoda.